# fatal error: opencv2/dnn.hpp: No such file or directory (opencv4)

Tags: opencv

Dnn library seems to be missing from `/usr/include/opencv2`. I have tried reinstalling but nothing changes. The `dnn/` folder and `dnn.hpp` file is still missing.

Answer (score 1):

on ubuntu20.04, you can install the dnn module directly:

```sh
root@gemfield:/home/gemfield/github/SYSZUX-FACE/build/bin# apt search opencv | grep dnn

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libopencv-dnn-dev/focal,now 4.2.0+dfsg-5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  development files for libopencv-dnn4.2
libopencv-dnn4.2/focal,now 4.2.0+dfsg-5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

On older release, you may either setup proper ppa, or compile from source.